# Where to find Google Apps Script's supported syntax?

Tags: google-apps-script

According to this page: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features, *"Apps Script is based on JavaScript 1.6, plus a few features from 1.7 and 1.8."*. But Google doesn't clearly specify what features from 1.7 and 1.8 which they support. So is there any information somewhere that tell specifically all of the syntax features available in Apps Script?

Comment: Currently no. However, Google plans to upgrade Apps Script to leverage Chrome's V8 Javascript engine, with full support for ES6 syntax. Google has yet to provide an ETA for when these features will arrive but its on the way. [You can check out the 2018 Google I/O announcement for more details](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGkcbP5Gd1o&feature=youtu.be&t=2161).

Comment: You can also check the release notes [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support).

Comment: Mostly array methods(like Array#filter). You can find them from Autocomplete / @types/google-apps-script - no straight up documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I see that GAS has its own "foreach" syntax, but it isn't documented anywhere in documentation. 
Guess I have to test myself and wait for the V8 Engine.